# Skip simple quote in a h2 database query

Tags: special-characters, velocity, h2

I'm trying to create an SQL file to execute in a h2 database. this file is generated from a modeling tool (magicdraw) based on the apache velocity syntax.

The problem is that some text fields I generate contains simple quotes, and this cannot be executed in h2.

example of the velocity script:

```
#foreach($cl in $Class) INSERT into myclass(id, description) VALUES ('$cl.id','$cl.description') #end
```

this script create an insert item for each element of the Class set. the description field may contain a simple quote... :/

any help please?

Comment: the solution is to put the description field in a dollar quoted string:

    #foreach($cl in $Class) INSERT into myclass(id, description) 
    VALUES ('$cl.id', $$ $cl.description $$) #end

Comment: The dollar quoted string is not a complete solution, because using two dollar signs within the text will not work (-> "SQL injection").